# Prove Vertex Connectivity in a Graph

Tags: graph-theory

If δ(G) ≥ n − 2 then prove that κ(G) = δ(G), where

```
δ(G) - Minimum degree of G
κ(G) - Vertex connectivity of G
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably $G$ has order $n$. Whitney's inequality tells us that $\kappa(G) \le \delta(G)$. Suppose the statement is true and there is a vertex cut $U$ of $G$ with $|U| = r < n-2$ in which case $\kappa(G) < \delta(G)$. Consider the components $G_1$ and $G_2$ of $G-U$, and let $G_1$ be the component having least order with $|G_1| = n_1$. Then $n_1 \le \lfloor{(n-r)/2}\rfloor$.

Let $v$ be a vertex of $G_1$. The neighborhood of $v$ can only be vertices of $G_1$ and $U$. So $deg(v) \le n_1-1+r \le \lfloor{(n-r)/2}\rfloor-1+r = \lfloor(n+r-2)/2\rfloor < (n+(n-2)-2)/2 = n-2$. This is a contradiction since $\delta(G) \ge n-2$.